# Square Root Transformation on a Random Variable

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I read in my textbook that if Y ~ N(0,1) and Z is exponential with mean 1 (f(x) = exp(-x)), then X ~ sqrt(2Z)*Y follows a double exponential (Laplace) distribution with parameter 1 (f(x) = 1/2 exp(-|x|).  How would one go about showing this, with regards to the square root?  Simply taking the square root of the pdf and multiplying doesn't work.

Comment: I think I found what I need here:
http://math.arizona.edu/~jwatkins/f-transform.pdf

It describes transforms on random variables.